# Converting into correct amount- Index error: string index out of range

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to bring `-` sign from the back/front of the string and convert the amount to the right sign.

```py
def convert_neg_back(x):
    
    x = x.replace(',', '')
    
    if x == '0':
        return float(0)
    
    elif x[-1] == '-':
        return -1 * float(x[0:-1])
    
    else:
        return float(x)
    
def convert_neg_front(x):
    
    x = x.replace(',', '')
    
    if x == '0':
        return float(0)
    
    elif x[1] == '-':
        return -1 * float(x[0:-1])
    
    else:
        return float(x)
```

Wanted to convert this column:

```py
df['B_Col_1'] = df['C_Col_1'].apply(lambda row : convert_neg_back(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you getting error because of empty string:

Try to add if condition like below, after function:

```
  def convert_neg_back_front(x): #, merge both functions into one, 
      if x:
         x = x.replace(',', '')

         if x == '0':
           return float(0)

         elif x[-1] == '-' or x[0]=='-':  #Also I guess you need to check Zero positon instead of 1 for front '-'
           return -1 * float(x[0:-1])

         else:
           return float(x)
```

Print:

```
print(convert_neg_back_front(''))    #Empty
print(convert_neg_back_front('0,'))  #Comma
print(convert_neg_back_front('0'))   #Zero
print(convert_neg_back_front('12,000'))   #comma
print(convert_neg_back_front('1-'))   #back
print(convert_neg_back_front('-1'))   #front
```

Output:

```
None
0.0
0.0
12000.0
-1.0
-1.0
```

python `bool(x)` returns `False`, if its empty.

Comment: So instead of  x ==  '0' or '-', I should use x : '0' or '-' ?

Comment: No, you can keep your code same just add if statement at very beginning of functions.

Comment: I see it is giving error at line elif x[-1] == '-': . specifically at x[-1]

Comment: Please add youre input data to I can assist you further.

Comment: I update the code and comments. please check

Comment: Hi, It worked when i combine the both fucntions together. Thanks.